# Transform format of date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following date `Thu Apr 02 2020 11:57:21 GMT+0200 (Středoevropský letní čas)`. I need to compare this date with the date that is stored in API. The problem is that the date in API is in this format `2020-06-27T12:34:00.000Z`.

Is there any way I can transform the format of the first date to be the same as the second date? Or can I comprare them in some way, that the formats wont matter?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
const date = new Date("Thu Apr 02 2020 11:57:21 GMT+0200 (Středoevropský letní čas)");
const formattedDate = date.toISOString(); // This the formatted date
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Use [Date.prototype.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

> The toISOString() method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format (ISO 8601),
>   which is always 24 or 27 characters long (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` or `±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`, respectively).
>   The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z".

```js
const time = 'Thu Apr 02 2020 11:57:21 GMT+0200 (Středoevropský letní čas)'

const result = new Date(time).toISOString();

console.log(result);
```